# Wireshark Dissector VoidString type

Tags: c++, lua, wireshark, kali-linux

I am working on a Wireshark Dissector Generator for a senior project. I have done some reading but had a question about the VoidString object in the ProtoField Object. The [documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/Proto#ProtoField) wasn't too clear on this particular value or what its used for.

Our generator uses C++ so that our client can modify it after the project is complete. I was reading in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261175/what-is-a-voidstring-object) that it could be passed a table of key, value pairs. Are there other structures or information this parameter is used for? We're trying to make a data structure to contain the parse of a file passed by the user and we're trying to determine how to best make this object. Would it be better to allow a template object to be passed here instead or is the table sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your needs but according to the wireshark source code (*wslua_proto_fields.c*), the definition of the *VoidString* parameter is :

```
#define WSLUA_OPTARG_ProtoField_new_VALUESTRING 4 /* A table containing the text that
    corresponds to the values, or a table containing unit name for the values if base is
    `base.UNIT_STRING`, or one of `frametype.NONE`, `frametype.REQUEST`, `frametype.RESPONSE`,
    `frametype.ACK` or `frametype.DUP_ACK` if field type is ftypes.FRAMENUM. */
```

So the table will be *"cast"* following the *type* and print in *base* representation.